# sum unique values after array join in PRESTO

Tags: sql, presto

I have 3 columns as below

| col1 | col2 | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12345 | 10 |
| abc | 12345 | 15 |
| bcd | 45689 | 15 |
| abc | 78945 | 20 |
| bcd | 54782 | 13 |
| def | 12345 | 10 |
| def | 12345 | 10 |

I looking to get result as below. Sum the price only once for col2 value. For ex. 12345 has $10 & $15. So I want to consider only once. anyting is fine (10 or 15) but only once in the sum

| col1 | col2 | count | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12345,78945 | 2 | 30 |
| bcd | 45689,54782 | 2 | 28 |
| def | 12345 | 1 | 10 |

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to presto to test so I have tested in mySQL and converted.
I have used a sub-query to get the average price for each col1 - col2 pair using `avg()`. You could use `min()` or `max()` if preferred or if `avg()` is not recognised in presto.

```
select
col1,
array_join(array_agg(col2), ','),
sum(av_price)
from 
  (  select 
     col1,col2, avg(price) av_price
     from p
     group by col1,col2
  ) as subQuery
group by col1
order by col1;
```

Here is the version mySQL, the result and the dbFiddle link

> ```
> select
> col1,
> group_concat(col2),
> sum(av_price)
> from 
>   (  select 
>      col1,col2, avg(price) av_price
>      from p
>      group by col1,col2
>   ) as subQuery
> group by col1
> order by col1
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | group_concat(col2) | sum(av_price)
> :--- | :----------------- | ------------:
> abc  | 12345,78945        |       32.5000
> bcd  | 45689,54782        |       28.0000
> def  | 12345              |       10.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=10b610d9c7c6dc251e0488d4e16e935a)*